# How to *Fully* Automate an Ubuntu Install?

Tags: scripts, compiling, automation

I currently am in a pickle where I have to install Ubuntu on up to hundreds of machines and I cannot use my right hand right now due to an injury. I need a simple way to completely automate the installer through bash, preferably. I want to just stick the disc in the computer and turn it on and have it install. The only variable needs to be a randomly generated password. I have a script for that part. I am not sure where to start with automating the install, however. Is there a way to do this? Somewhere I can place a script or config in the iso maybe? Is there a way to interface with and customize the installer iso so I can just tell it ahead of time how to partition, what the hostname is, etc?

Any help would be eternally appreciated.

Update: This might help someone down the line, so my advice if you have many of the same devices to install and configure on OS on is to pick up a [usb rubber ducky](https://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe) and program it to click through the installations and run a post install shell script if need be.

The ducky is a programmable keyboard that types for you, and I have successfully used this to automate & configure a bunch of Ubuntu installs, as well as [Android tablets](https://github.com/darkerego/kindleDucky).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a short way to do automation to anything, especially when we talk about OS!

There will be a number of cases, such as partitioning the disk, only if it will wipe the whole drive and just copy paste the System files without any other consideration.

Well, you are right when mentioning Shell scripting as a solution to this  because that is why we do coding since the early ages of technology, but I advice you to have a look at this link before you really want to dive into this really WIDE stuff - [FAI Project](http://fai-project.org/).

**It says :**

> It's a tool for unattended mass deployment of Linux. You can take one or more virgin PC's, turn on the power, and after a few minutes, the systems are installed, and completely configured to your exact needs, without any interaction necessary.

In  practice [Fully Automatic Installation XUbuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Vw9NJ9KVfE)

Comment: Nice, that certaintly looks like what I am looking for. I'll give it a shot and report back. Thank you!